# rbinding list of matrices while keeping their names using Reduce

Tags: r

I have a list

```
myList <- list(matrix(letters[1:4], nrow=2), matrix(letters[5:8], nrow=2))
names(myList) <- c("xx", "yy")
```

I want to rbind this list of matrix, along with the names `xx` and `yy`, using `Reduce`. The problem I have is that `Reduce` goes directly to `myList[[i]]` so it loses the names if I pass `myList` directly. I'm guessing the solution is some combination of creating more 'layers' and clever use of `[`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

The desired output is

```
"xx"
"a" "c"
"b" "d"
"yy"
"e" "g"
"f" "h"
```

Comment: I gave you the output but I could not make sense of the request to "rbind" these items. They have different column lengths. Maybe you should say what you really want to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(MASS)

for( nm in names(myList)){ cat(nm,"\n"); write.matrix(myList[[nm]]) }

xx 
a c
b d
yy 
e g
f h
```